# Updating WIT field using Work Item Custom Controls

Tags: tfs

Need code for Updating WIT field using Work Item Custom Controls while creating new WIT.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far and other ideas you had about how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the power tools (tfpt) and then you can download a WIT via: Tools>ProcessEditor>ExportWit. You can edit it locally then using the same tool.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your suggestion, but now I am doing the same with Build definition using custom build activity.